# Java server works in 32-bit, but not in 64-bit. Why?

Tags: java, sockets, 64-bit, serversocket, java-server

I get this strange exception on only when running on 64 bit (windows 7 ultimate)  Not when running 32 bit win7 ultimate.   Currently its running on java version 1.6.0_26

```
running server!
java.net.SocketException: select failed
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
 at Server.main(Server.java:18)
```

Here is the code:

```
//import java.net.ServerSocket;
//import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;




public class Server {


 public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.println("running server!");
  int nreq = 1;
  try{
   ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(7337);
  for(;;){
   Socket newsock = sock.accept();
   System.out.println("Creating thread...");
   Thread t = new ThreadHandler(newsock, nreq);
   t.start();
   nreq++;
  }
  }

  catch(Exception e)
  {

   e.printStackTrace();

  }
 }
}
```

The error referenced on line at points to this bit:

```
Socket newsock = sock.accept();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can cause “ IO error java.net.SocketException: select failed ”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926655/what-can-cause-io-error-java-net-socketexception-select-failed)

Comment: The question was never satisfactorily answered.  It was not a firewall issue or admin privileges problem

Comment: I'm new here and unaware of his prowess, but I assume this fact should convey hopelessness

Comment: When you have more than 75 points of reputation, you could [put a bounty on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) (it will cost you your 50 points) - it might attract more answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could definitely have an issue with windows 7 and the version of Java SDK you have installed.  Download and install the latest version of Java SDK 7 from the oracle website.  See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

These problems can happen, when there's a mismatch between JVM and OS. One running 32 bit and the other running 64 bit.

Comment: In general, you should be able to run any Java program with a 32-bit JRE running on a 64-bit OS.  And in general, you shouldn't even be able to *START* a 64-bit JVM on a 32-bit OS (it should die long before you get any networking error).  But yes, I would definitely encourage running a 64-bit JRE on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: Currently its running on  java version
1.6.0_26  I'll try some others

Answer (score 0):

I do *not* believe the problem is Java 32-bit vs. 64-bit.

The problem *could* be Windows 32-bit vs. Windows 64-bit, however:

- [What can cause “ IO error java.net.SocketException: select failed ”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926655/what-can-cause-io-error-java-net-socketexception-select-failed)

ALSO:

1) Please try running with this JVM option:

- -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

2) Please make sure you've installed the *64-bit* version of Java

Comment: That was an old account which I lost the password for.  I've never seen anyone able to solve this yet (or have the same issue).  One thing I had tried before was downgrading the version of java to a different one.  It had the same problem